# Each with index with object in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to iterate over an array and conditionally increment a counter. I am using index to compare to other array's elements:

```
elements.each_with_index.with_object(0) do |(element, index), diff|
  diff += 1 unless other[index] == element
end
```

I can't get `diff` to change value even when changing it unconditionally.
This can be solved with `inject`:

```
elements.each_with_index.inject(0) do |diff, (element, index)|
  diff += 1 unless other[index] == element
  diff
end
```

But I am wondering if `.each_with_index.with_object(0)` is a valid construction and how to use it?

Comment: can't you do `(elements & other).size`?

Comment: @j03W It doesn't compare 2 elements with same index as a pair, but returns an intersection of 2 arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From ruby docs for [each_with_object](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object)

> Note that you can’t use immutable objects like numbers, true or false
>   as the memo. You would think the following returns 120, but since the
>   memo is never changed, it does not.
>
> (1..5).each_with_object(1) { |value, memo| memo *= value } # => 1

So `each_with_object` does not work on immutable objects like integer.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You want to count the number of element wise differences, right?

```
elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
other    = [1, 2, 0, 4, 5]
#                 ^
```

I'd use [`Array#zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) to combine both arrays element wise and [`Array#count`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-count) to count the unequal pairs:

```
elements.zip(other).count { |a, b| a != b }  #=> 1
```

Comment: Good point. This is the most natural solution to the problem but I was asking about `each_with_index.with_object`

Comment: You're right, it doesn't answer it. I just wanted to add an alternative because your approach looked a bit complicated :)